# insert to 2 tables from single form code is giving problem----please help

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webform, from which i want records should be submitted into two tables under same database name.

My code is

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","************","***********");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db=mysql_select_db("qserves1_uksurvey", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO forms (date, Receivingsky, Title, Firstname, Lastname, House, Street, Town, County, Postcode, Number, WarrantyCoverForSky, Tvmake, Warrantycover, Payingmonthly, Agentnotes, Agentname)
VALUES
(NOW(),'$_POST[Receivingsky]','$_POST[Title]','$_POST[Firstname]','$_POST[Lastname]','$_POST[House]','$_POST[Street]','$_POST[Town]','$_POST[County]','$_POST[Postcode]','$_POST[Number]','$_POST[WarrantyCoverForSky]','$_POST[Tvmake]','$_POST[Warrantycover]','$_POST[Payingmonthly]','$_POST[Agentnotes]','$_POST[Agentname]')";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die (mysql_error());

$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","*******8","*********8");
if (!$con2)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db2=mysql_select_db("qserves1_uksurvey", $con2);

$sql2="INSERT INTO dupphones (date, Number)
Values
(NOW(),'$_POST[Number]')";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql2, $con2) or die (mysql_error());

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo '<html>
<head>
<title>Lead Submitted successfully!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<strong><a href="http://q2serves.com/uksurvey.html">Lead Submitted ---- Click Here To Enter New Lead</a></strong>
</center>
</body>
</html>!'; 

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

This is submitting 3 leads 1 is in table dupphones and 2 leads in table forms.

I want this to submit 1 lead in each table only.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Why do you create two connections to the same database? You also execute mysql_query numerous times, sometimes with $sql2, then again with $sql.

Comment: Just a few words of advice. Sanitize your $_POST data before you submit. And consider using a primary key. Also, why do you make a new connection to run the second query?

Answer (score 0):

You create two connections to the same database. You also execute mysql_query numerous times, sometimes with $sql2, then again with $sql. To clear up your code a little bit this is how it could look:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","************","***********");
if (!$con) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db=mysql_select_db("qserves1_uksurvey", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO forms (date, Receivingsky, Title, Firstname, Lastname, House, Street, Town, County, Postcode, Number, WarrantyCoverForSky, Tvmake, Warrantycover, Payingmonthly, Agentnotes, Agentname)
VALUES
(NOW(),'$_POST[Receivingsky]','$_POST[Title]','$_POST[Firstname]',
'$_POST[Lastname]','$_POST[House]','$_POST[Street]','$_POST[Town]','$_POST[County]',
'$_POST[Postcode]','$_POST[Number]','$_POST[WarrantyCoverForSky]','$_POST[Tvmake]',
'$_POST[Warrantycover]','$_POST[Payingmonthly]','$_POST[Agentnotes]',
'$_POST[Agentname]')";
 $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die (mysql_error());

 $sql2="INSERT INTO dupphones (date, Number)
 Values
 (NOW(),'$_POST[Number]')";
 $sql_result = mysql_query($sql2, $con2) or die (mysql_error());

echo '<html>
<head>
```

Note that your queries are still vulnerable to sql injection. Use escaping or prepared statements to get rid of sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a few words of advice. Sanitize your $_POST data before you submit**. And consider using a primary key. Also, why do you make a new connection to run the second query?

At least use `mysql_real_escape()`

You get two queries because you do

```
  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

Which runs the query again. You already run it once on top

```
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die (mysql_error());
```